# Flutter: GetX Obx() could not rebuild ListView items

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-listview

I am working on a simple ListView. I managed to update the list view with the correct data, see `items` which is `<String>[].obs`, when it got populated the data, I can see the list view is populated.

However, it seems after the list view items are built, they are not observing my `selected` change, which is `0.obs`. From the debugging code, I can see the `selected` got updated, the title changes accordingly, but the list view items did not rebuild (and hence change color), and not reflecting if they are being selected.

Please help me to understand why `selected` change did not trigger list item rebuild, and how to fix. Thanks!

My `home_controller.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  final loading = true.obs;
  final items = <String>[].obs;
  final selected = 0.obs;

  final count = 0.obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchItems();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<void> fetchItems() async {
    loading.value = true;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      final newItems = ['abc', 'def', 'ghij', 'klmnopq'];
      items.assignAll(newItems);
      loading.value = false;
    });
  }

  void onHover(int index) {
    selected.value = index;
    print('onHover: $index');
  }
}
```

And my `home_view.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:
            Obx(() => Text('HomeView: selected ${controller.selected.value}')),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Obx(() => Center(
            child: controller.loading.value
                ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controller.items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final color = controller.selected.value == index
                          ? Colors.green
                          : Colors.grey;
                      return MouseRegion(
                        onHover: (event) {
                          controller.onHover(index);
                        },
                        onExit: ((event) {
                          final selected = controller.selected.value;
                          print(
                              'exiting: $index, current selected: ${selected}');
                        }),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading:
                              Container(width: 40, height: 40, color: color),
                          title: Text(controller.items[index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe wrapping your `MouseRegion` with another `Obx` would solve it for you.  It being inside another builder will not make it able to be observed by the outer `Obx`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explained the issue! Obx on the MouseRegion only is not enough, but need to include the `color` calculation as well.